# In The Fades, why doesn't Paul just jump from the building on the roof of which he's "trapped" by John?

Tags: the-fades

In [episode 4 of The Fades](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b015v0nh), why doesn't Paul just jump from the building on the roof of which he's "trapped" by John? He may not be able to open doors, but he can certainly jump off the roof, and if he's already dead, the impact can presumably do him no harm.

Answer (score 0):

**Paul didn't want to escape from John**

Instead of doing it by killing himself (as suggested in the question), Paul, while learning the true horrors of being a ghost, with all the restrictions and limits of being a Fade, he wanted to know more about his current condition. Was he really dead? Could he get back again in his brain dead (comatose) body?

Paul also wants to know why John is the man of his apocalyptic ash dreams.

Indeed, Paul accedes to take John, the angelical killer, to the bunker to rescue his wife after learning from John about what the Angelics have been doing with the Fades and what they considered their task to save the human race from them.